# Java How to use class object for List initialisation

Tags: java

How to use a class object to assign the type of the List  ?

```
public void assign(Class name){
 List<name> xlist = new ArrayList();
}
```

Comment: you could use `Object` and cast it later to the specific type

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @user3703592 `public <T> void assign(T t) { List<T> xlist = new ArrayList<>(); }`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not sure if it's a dup since OP's not returning `xlist` anywhere.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not about the question. It's about the answers. The accept answer (and the others) explain how to do what they are trying to do, even though it's pointless in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do:

```
public <T> void assign(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> xlist = new ArrayList<>();
    /*
        more code here...
    */
}
```

Comment: I believe it's because the `Class<T> clazz` is kind of pointless here.

Comment: @CKing it's not pointless. The method is `void` so w/o a parameter, there's no way to obtain `T`. And `xlist` is not returned anywhere.

Comment: Wouldn't `T` instead of `Class<T>` suffice?

Comment: @CKing nope. Test it yourself. Of course, I assume the generic is at method level, not at class level.

Comment: `public <T> void assign(T t) {
     List<T> xlist = new ArrayList<>();
     /*
         more code here...
     */
 }` This works fine for me. Why the `Class<T>`?

Comment: @CKing in that case, you need to pass an object reference. With this one, you only need to pass the `Class` reference. `Class<T> clazz` is not pointless, is just another way to ensure the type. Check [`CheckedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Class-) and similar methods as an example.

Comment: How to call the assign function ? `assign(Input.class)` does not work

Comment: @user3703592 define *does not work*.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I forgot an interface

Answer (score 1):

You can make the method generic :

```
public <T> void assign(){
    List<T> xlist = new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Or the generic type parameter can be declared at the class level (the class that contains the `assign` method).

This way you don't need to pass a `Class` instance to your method.

Comment: Careful. The method is `void`. With that implementation, there's no way to obtain `T` from anywhere.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You can call, for example,  `test.<String>createList();`, assuming `test` is an instance of the class that contains that method. You don't need a return type.

Comment: I know that, but AFAIK that's not common Java code. Just trying to avoid that way of coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
public <T> void assign(Class<T> name) {
    List<T> xlist = new ArrayList<>();
}
```